# Object reference required for non static fields

Tags: c#

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

if I remove the static modifier then i have a problem when i call items.getTotal() if i add it back into the method then i get a problem returning the number field.

Any help with this would be appreciated I'm still learning.

I've marked below beside with comments which line i have error in.

```
namespace Something
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<items> item = new List<items>();
        int choice;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please select an option:");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Create item:");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Destroy last item:");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Exit:");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Write("Name of new item:");
                    items obj = new items(Console.ReadLine());
                    item.Add(obj);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (item.Count > 0)
                    {
                        item[new item.Count - 1].RemoveOne(); /*<<error*/
                        item.RemoveAt(item.Count - 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:

                    Console.WriteLine("Total number of items:" + items.getTotal()); /*<<error*/
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
class items
{
    //write your code here

    private string name;
    private int number;



    public items(string a)
    {
        this.name = a;
        this.number++;
        Console.WriteLine("successfully created");
    }
    public void RemoveOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.name);
        this.number = this.number + 1;   
    }

    public int getTotal()
    { 
        return number;
    }



}

}
```

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?  You can edit your question to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your fields, properties and methods are instance scoped, and some are static.  You need to be consistent in order for them to access each other.

Something that is static means that it is associated with the class itself.  When something is not static, it is associated with a specific instance of the class.

Given what you seem to be working on, I suggest you remove `static` from getTotal():

```
public int getTotal()
{ 
    return number;
}
```

> If I remove the static modifier then i have a problem when i call items.getTotal() if i add it back into the method then i get a problem returning the number field.

I'm not sure which "static modifier" you are referring to.  If you remove it from getTotal(), I don't see anything that would obviously break.  If something does, update your question with the specific line that breaks.

**UPDATE**

The line

```
item[new item.Count - 1].RemoveOne(); /*<<error*/
```

should not have the `new` keyword in it.  Simply `item.Count - 1` will give you the index of the last element in `item`.

The line

```
items.getTotal()
```

is giving you problems because `items` is the name of a class, not a variable.  That syntax will try to call a *static* method on the class called `getTotal()`.  You probably mean

```
item.getTotal()
```

which refers to your instantiated `List<items>`.

See also the following note about casing.  It will make it easier to avoid this type of issue.

**About Style**

I suggest you follow the [C# coding conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx), that [specify that classes and methods shall be CamelCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g.

```
class Items
{
    public int GetTotal()
    { 
        return number;
    }
}
```

Following that convention makes your code much easier for others to read, and for you as well.

Comment: I updated the question and removed the static from the GetTotal() method I get errors on two lines.

Comment: This makes complete sense I was trying to follow online tutorial on Programmr.com so i didn't want to modify it. I've revised the code but the following still pops up as an error. List<.items> does not contain a definition for 'GetTotal' accepting a first argument of type List<.items> could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Looks like you have an extra dot?  `List<.items>` should be `List<items>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This leads me to more questions about Generics now which I'll post in another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int getTotal()
    { 
        return number;
    }
```

You can't reference number inside getTotal since number is an instance member and getTotal is static. Static members are defined at the type level, so there is no knowledge of specific instance based members, so it's invalid to make a reference to an instance member from a static type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the static method **getTotal()** gets the default value of **private int number;**.

What you must do is either make the **number** field static or make the method **getTotal()** non-static.

You must create an instance of the **item class** and then from the instance, you can call the getTotal() method.

Example

```
item myItem = new item();
myItem.getTotal();
```